# LM358DR as LMV358 replacement

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, power, arduino-uno

So I have an Arduino Uno here that I mistakenly put 24V on the VIN pin, and as a result, the LMV358 on it popped the Magic Smoke.

My question is, can I replace it with a LM358? I asked this question on Arduino forums and someone said the LMV358 is "rail to rail", so I am hesitating to go with the replacing. Does the "rail-to-rail" feature really matter?

Answer (score 2):

It would not be a good idea. Here is the relevant portion of the Arduino Uno [schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Uno_Rev3-schematic.pdf):

[image]

The output of U5A has to get very close to the positive rail in order to turn T1 off fully, and the LM358 cannot do that, so it would not properly isolate the power derived from POWERIN from the USB port when VIN is present.

Easiest thing is to get a proper replacement part (and replace anything else which may have been damaged in this 'incident'). If the 24V has found its way onto the supply bus, the unit may not be economically repairable.